# jQuery Validate method checking for special characters

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am trying (and failing) to write a regular expression statement that checks for special characters such as !@#$%^&*()_+<>?'"{}[] in my Javascript form validation.

I understand that this has probably been asked 1000 times but i'm under some serious time pressure. If you would rather not answer the question below and you are able to point me in the direction of a previous answer to the above question I would greatly appreciate it.

On a similar note, can anyone tell me why the following is shooting an error when I enter lowercase 'abc', etc? I'm baffled.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("specialChars", function( value, element ) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);

        if (!regex.test(key)) {
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }
    }, "please use only alphanumeric or alphabetic characters");
```

Comment: pktangyue I thought key was just a variable name? What does it refer to? I think i may have copied that as an earlier attempt from somewhere.

Comment: Why are you writing a method that already exists in the Validate plugin?  Within the `additional-methods.js` file is a rule called `alphanumeric`.  See:  http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js

Comment: I thought you should test `value`, which is inputed by user.

Comment: @sparky beat me to it....also how did you get `event.which`, or `event.preventDefault` into a validation method for a form field?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Instead of writing your own custom method from scratch, include the [`additional-methods.js`](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/additional-methods.js) file and use the `alphanumeric` rule.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field: {
                alphanumeric: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/YsAKx/**

---

If you don't want to include an additional external file, simply copy the default `alphanumeric` method out of it...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\w+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters, numbers, and underscores only please");
```

Answer (score 10):

Few changes

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("specialChars", function( value, element ) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        var key = value;

        if (!regex.test(key)) {
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }, "please use only alphanumeric or alphabetic characters");
```

1. You need to return the value true, if the test is valid
2. The validator is not a event handler so you cannot use `event.preventDefault()`, this has to be done in the `keypress` event.
3. You need to test the value passed to the validate method.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KVdpU/2/)

Note: Since you are using `+` wild char at least one character is required in the text box, you may want to split it into two rules using the `required` rule and change the wild char to `*`.

Comment: @hyperdouche as Sparky suggested, there is a built in rule already present with the library, suggest using it

Comment: Crap, okay, thanks. I had written my replies and marked as correct before refreshing the page. Maybe i'll go back and investigate that then.

Comment: Helpful, returning `true` or `false` saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9;,.!@#$%:{}[]?"^&*()/\']*|[^&;<>\`]*
```

you want special charecter add here in this [] braces `^[a-zA-Z0-9;,.!@#$%:{}[]?"^&*()/\']` and you dont want then add here this part `[^&;<>\`]`