# validation of password field whether it contains special characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This code checks for password entered whether it contains min 8 character. I want to check password whether it has special character. If there isnot special character the user must be prompt to enter special character and number.
Jquery code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#changePasswordForm").validate({
        rules: {
            oldPassword: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            password2: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#password1", minlength: 8
            }
        }
    });
});
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "<span>This field is required.</span>",
    equalTo: "<span>Please enter the same value again.</span>",
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("<span>Please enter at least {0} characters.</span>")
});
```

Comment: This might help, essentially you can define your own rule: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949257/jquery-validate-method-checking-for-special-characters

Comment: Define a custom method that checks the syntax of your password against your desired rule. See `$.validator.addMethod()`.

Comment: these restrict special character. i want those special characters in my password. so it should check if they exists. if not should prompt user to enter atleast one special character and number.

Comment: @user3762522 see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yb6cn8gm/1/

Answer (score 1):

To check if a string contains a certain character, You can use a regular expression.
By using a regExp, You can also choose which special characters to accept. 
You can either adjust the regular expression to a variable

```
var regExp = /[*listofyourspecialcharacters*]/;
```

or You can use it directly

```
/[*listofyourspecialcharacters*]/.test(*yourstring*);
```

The test method searches the string given as a parameter and returns true, if the regular expression matches, i.e. when a special character is found and returns false if not. 
So You can easily check Your users input as soon as he hits a confirmation button or when the value of Your input field changes.
e.g.:

```
$("#acceptButton").click(function(){
     var regExp = /[_\-!\"@;,.:]/;
     if(!regExp.test($('#password1').val())){
         *askForNewPassword();*
     } else {
         *carry on()*;
     }
};
```

EDIT: the open and close brackets ('[', ']') in the reg exp are NOT part of the characters against which the string gets checked. They just hold the list of characters you want to use. If you want to use them, you need to use an escape sign:

```
var regExp = /[;:_\-!@\"\]\[]/;
```