# To detect special character in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to identify special characters like @, # in a input string using JavaScript but it's not working. Below is my JavaScript code.

```
function check_cr_title(selected_cr_str)
    {
        if(selected_cr_str != '')
        {
            if(selected_cr_str.match(^[@#]+$))

             { 
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").html(selected_cr_str + ' Contains Special character.');
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").css('color','red');
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").css('display','block');
                jQuery("#cr_title").val('');


             }
             else
            {
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").html('');
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").css('display','none');

            }

        }


    }
```

For input I am using below code.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column1 columnheader ">CR Title</div>
    <div class="column2 column-input width100"><input name="cr_tile" type="text" value="" onblur="check_cr_title(this.value)" required></div>
  <span id="check_valid_cr_span" style="display:none;width:1000px;"></span>
  </div>
```

Please help me to get this solution.

Comment: Are you trying to match that the whole string consists of just special chars? Or just whether the string contains special chars? If the latter then you should drop the start and end markers

Comment: i am taking a input as string. i want to check if any special character exists in that string or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate method checking for special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949257/jquery-validate-method-checking-for-special-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make it this way:

```
if(selected_cr_str.match(/[@#]/g))
```

Here is the full code:

```js
    function check_cr_title(selected_cr_str)
    {
        if(selected_cr_str != '')
        {
            if(selected_cr_str.match(/[@#]/g))

             { 
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").html(selected_cr_str + ' Contains Special character.');
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").css('color','red');
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").css('display','block');
                jQuery("#cr_title").val('');


             }
             else
            {
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").html('');
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").css('display','none');

            }

        }


    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column1 columnheader ">CR Title</div>
    <div class="column2 column-input width100"><input name="cr_tile" type="text" value="" onblur="check_cr_title(this.value)" required></div>
  <span id="check_valid_cr_span" style="display:none;width:1000px;"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's working if @ and # is at the beginning but not working if these character is in middle of a string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
unction check_cr_title(selected_cr_str)
    {
        if(selected_cr_str != '')
        {
            if(selected_cr_str.match(('\^[@# ]+$\')))

             { 
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").html(selected_cr_str + ' Contains Special character.');
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").css('color','red');
                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").css('display','block');
                jQuery("#cr_title").val('');


             }
             else
            {
    jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").html('');                jQuery("#check_valid_cr_span").css('display','none');

            }

        }


    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column1 columnheader ">CR Title</div>
    <div class="column2 column-input width100"><input name="cr_tile" type="text" value="" onblur="check_cr_title(this.value)" required></div>
  <span id="check_valid_cr_span" style="display:none;width:1000px;"></span>
  </div>
```